# Pusher fails to connect in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, laravel-5.8

I used Pusher with laravel 5.4 and and no issues but now i'm trying to use laravel 5.8 and i get the following error. I've tried everything i can think of and even changed the `encrypted` to `false` just incase. I triple checked my pusher credentials.

Laravel Version `5.8`

PHP Version `7.2.18`

OS `OSX`

Error I'm getting

```
$response = $this->pusher->trigger(
            $this->formatChannels($channels), $event, $payload, $socket, true
        );

        if ((is_array($response) && $response['status'] >= 200 && $response['status'] <= 299)
            || $response === true) {
            return;
        }

        throw new BroadcastException(
            is_bool($response) ? 'Failed to connect to Pusher.' : $response['body']
        );
```

My ENV file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=XXXXXX
PUSHER_APP_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=us2
```

My Event File

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\ChatRoomMessage;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class NewMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param ChatRoomMessage $chatRoomMessage
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('message');
    }
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/broadcast', function() {
    event(new \App\Events\NewMessage);
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you fixed it?

Comment: @HVD nope i never finished that project because i couldn't find any solution. I'm planning to revisit the project if i find any update i'll make sure to let you know. and if you find any solunstions please let me know. i would much appreciate it.

Comment: Problem solved. You can try download cacert from here [link](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html). Then open php.ini and change **;curl.cainfo =** to **curl.cainfo = "path to cacert downloaded**" (curl.cainfo = "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.2.14\extras\ssl\cacert-2019-05-15.pem")

Comment: NopeNopeNopeNope

Answer (score 0):

How to Fix Failed to connect to Pusher when using Laravel Valet with Php7.2 or above On Mac
———————————————————————————————————------------------

NB: I decided to write this because I don’t think anyone else should spend 5 hours fixing this, I have already done that.

```
Server : Valet;
 OS: Mac Mojave;
 PHP Version: 7.2;
```

In my case turning forceTLS to false worked but I did not like that solution.  Also adding:

```
'curl_options' => [
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
]
```

to my broadcasting.php file worked but for some reason I was not convinced with this solution too.

So I decided to make things work by downloading the CA bundle from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and moved the cacert.pem from the downloads folder into /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs (in my case I installed openssl1.1 using homebrew only because I was trying various things I find online just to make this work but now I know I do not need openssl1.1 you may go with the openssl folder you already have) so the full path to the cacert file becomes /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/cacert.pem   
Opening php.ini
 ——————---

From your terminal enter php --ini to find the path to the loaded php.ini (open that in your editor of choice; I use nano sometimes) Important: As of PHP 7.2 (Win 64) this directive, will NOT show in the phpinfo() even though it's set. (In comparison, an openssl.cafile directive will show, if it's set to the exact same path).

So now in your php.ini set the following to : (NB: replace the path to indicate where those files can be found on your system)  openssl.cafile = “/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/cacert.pem’ openssl.capath = “/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs” Take note: because I am using php7.2 I did not have to set curl.cainfo to anything; initially I spent so many hours trying to use curl.info method which did not work for me so in my final configuration I commented it by putting a semi-colon in front of it ( ;curl.cainfo ="/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/certs/cacert.pem”)

After this you should run valet restart which would restart some valet services but I realised even after valet restarts, my new php.ini changes are not reflecting when I do phpinfo();

Finally you should restart php by entering brew services restart php72 (NB: I installed php via homebrew so incase you did not , you would have to restart php differently)

Hope this helps . Even if it does not solve your problem exactly it would surely give you some ideas to try out just as I leveraged other peoples tiny bits of ideas from one page to another in coming up with my solution.