# pusher listener is not working even that the event has been fired succesfuly

Tags: php, laravel, pusher

i triggered a broadcast event succesfully but the problem is that the laravel echo listner was not fired

```
if(broadcast(new \App\Events\See("name"))){
        return true;
}
```

it return true and in my event class i write

```
public $name;
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name=$name;
    }



    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['my-channel'];
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return 'my-event';
    }
```

and in js listner

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
 window.Echo = new Echo({
                broadcaster: 'pusher',
                key: 'key',
                cluster: 'cluster var',
                forceTLS: true
            });

        var channel = Echo.channel('my-channel');
        channel.listen('my-event', function(data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        });`
```

this code is just a copy past from pusher website and i'm shure of the 
variable of the env
and i dowloaded laravel echo and the pusher change the brodcast driver env

Comment: Can you check the pusher website to see if the event was fired and received correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Do Laravel Echo library and JS Pusher package are installed?

```
npm install --save laravel-echo

npm install --save pusher-js
```

OR

```
npm install --save laravel-echo pusher-js
```

Comment: it didn't work i still got throw new BroadcastException(
            is_bool($response) ? 'Failed to connect to Pusher.' : $response['body']
        );

Comment: Go to this POST see if can help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42754318/laravel-5-4-event-broadcasting-not-work-with-vuejs/42938307#42938307

Comment: i just see another post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56352281/pusher-fails-to-connect-in-laravel-5-8 and it solve my probel my app can connect now to pusher

Comment: but i wonder how to display this data or to make a change in my html file

Comment: this is weird it work for me on the first times i just turned off the pc and when i try it again it gived the same error